# WACK Failed: The binary DrawerLayout.dll is built in debug mode

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, msdn

I am running windows app certification kit, 
- I have checked my Visual Studio Configuration Settings and they are set to Release | ARM. The version of WACK is 10.0 
- What should i do now to release my app ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the `DrawerLayout.dll` is external dependency you use in your project, probably https://github.com/amarmesic/windows-phone-navigation-drawer. If you compiled it from source, compile it (the `DrawerLayout.dll` in Release), or just add it from Nuget.